# How to print and read file in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I am following the book *OCaml from the very beginning* by John Whitington. In page 91-92 he discussed how to print and read values from OCaml. He claim that the code

```
let rec read_dict()=
  let i=read_int () in
  if i=0 then
    [] 
  else
    let name=read_line in 
    (i, name):: read_dict ();;

read_dict();;
```

should let me to take some input integer values and string values, and return me a list with pairs. But I cannot execute the code on my computer, and neither can I execute it successfully in the *Try Ocaml* website. May I ask what is wrong?

I tried in the OCaml toplevel in the windows IDE, in *utop* on Ubuntu, and on *Try OCaml* in the website. In the first instance the program keep running and nothing comes up. In the second it takes values but never ends. In the third instance it takes values, but give me an error message when I give a string value like One.

Comment: When you say that it took values but never ends, did you try giving `0` as the integer? That looks like what is supposed to end input.

Comment: Let me try to implement it again in Utop. However in the Try Ocaml website it does end with 0, but it cannot take any string value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `let name=read_line in` with `let name = read_line () in` and it should work at the command line (although not at the toplevel, which will mess with `stdin`).

Input should look something like

```
1
one
2
two
0
```

Comment: I tried your code, but it does not ask me to input anything. The function went through. Maybe I should try it again with utop.

Comment: It wont directly ask, but just start reading. you would have to print a statement to make the request nicer.

Answer (score 3):

Let's try it step-by-step. First of all create a file, named `input_dict.ml` and open it in your favorite text-editor.

Then put in it the following code:

```
open Printf

let rec read_dict () =
  let i = read_int () in
  if i = 0 then [] else
    let name = read_line () in
    (i, name) :: read_dict ()

(* The entry point. Read a dictionary and print it out. *)
let _main : unit =
  let dict = read_dict () in
  printf "dict = { ";
  List.iter (fun (i,n) -> printf "%d => %s; " i n) dict;
  printf " }\n"
```

I've added some printing to the end, just that you can be sure, that it works correctly.

Now save the file, proceed to the shell, make sure that you're in the directory with a file and compile and run your program with a command: `ocamlbuild input_dict.byte --`. (This two trailing dashes instruct `ocamlbuild` to run a program after the compilation). At the end this will look something like this:

```
$ ocamlbuild input_dict.byte --
42
Hello
56
World
0
dict = { 42 => Hello; 56 => World;  }
```

Please note, that you shouldn't run this program in an interactive mode, because your input will be "eaten" by the OCaml interpreter.

Comment: Hi!, I ran it, but nothing showed up. It only says"changwei@Sparkie-Virtual-Machine:~$ ocamlbuild input_dict.byte --
Finished, 3 targets (3 cached) in 00:00:00.
"

Comment: I understood it wrong. Now it is working! Thank you!

Comment: Because, this is you who should say something, it waits for your input. You should type `42` then hit `enter`, afterwards you should enter `Hello` and hit the enter, and so on, until you enter `0`. And then you will see the answer.